# LINQ Select Object based on a property within a list within the object

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to select a list of objects from a list of objects which has a list of objects of another type within itself based on a property within that list of objects.

For example

```
class TypeA{
  string Name {get; set;}
  List<TypeB> ListOfTypeB {get; set;}
}

class TypeB{
  int Age {get; set;}
  bool Active {get; set;}
}
```

I have a list of Type A which is populated by the database, I want to query the list of TypeA and Return a List of TypeA based on the Active property in TypeB which is a list within the TypeA object.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> I want to query the list of TypeA and Return a List of TypeA based on
>   the Active property in TypeB.

This specification is a bit unclear. I assume you mean that you want all `TypeA` objects that have at least one `TypeB` object with a true value `TypeB.Activity` (or those with a false one).

The answer depends on whether you want to perform your query as `Enumerable` or as `Queryable`. In words: Do you first want to get the objects into local memory and then perform the query (`AsEnumerable`) or do you want to let the database perform the query (`Asqueryable`) and then only return the valid results to local memory.

**AsEnumerable**

This method is not very efficient, because it would mean that you get the complete TypeA and TypeB table to local memory before processing.

However your query would be simple:

```
var AwithActivity = allTypeA
    .Where(a => a.ListOfTypeB.Any(b => b.Activity));
```

In words:

From the complete sequence of `typeA` elements, take only those `typeA` elements that have at least one `ListOfTypeB` element with a true value for property `Activity`.

**AsQueryable**

If your database is set up correctly you will have two tables. One table with `TypeA` items and one table with `TypeB` items.

`TypeA` has a one-to-many relation with `TypeB`. Every `TypeA` has zero or more `TypeB` and every `TypeB` belongs to exactly one `TypeA`.

In your database both `TypeA` and `TypeB` will have a primary key. Every `TypeB` will have a foreign key to the `TypeA` to wich it belongs.

This is fairly standard database. It helps you with your query. Using these definitions your query will be translated into:

> I want all TypeA objects of which there is at least one TypeB object that has a foreign key to this TypeA object AND a true value for Activity

The query will be:

```
var results = TypeATable            // groupjoin table TypeA with table TypeB
    .GroupJoin(TypeBTable,
      typeA => typeA.PrimaryKey,    // from every typeA use the primary key
      typeB => typeB.ForeignKey,    // from every typeB use the foreign key to the TypeA
      (a, allB) => new              // for every A with all matching typeB:
      {                             // create a new anonymous type
         A = a,                     // with the found A
         HasActivity = allB         // and a boolean that says if there was
            .Any(b => b.Activity),  // at least one B with a true Activity
      });
```

To get all TypeA with at least one activity:

```
var AWithActivity = results.Where(result => result.HasActivity)
   .Select(result => result.A);
```

To get all TypeA that have no activity at all:

```
var AwithoutActivity = result.Where(result => !result.HasActivity)
   .Select(result => result.A);
```

**Addition**
If could be that the relation between a typeA and typeB is not one-to-many, but many-to-many. In that case, you take all active typeB objects and find all typeA objects with foreign keys to this active typeB object

Comment: Hi yes your correct, I re-read my reply and it is a little vague, my schema and relationships are well structure as you have described. What I was over thinking was the possibility of nested select query. Thanks for the detailed answer it has made me look at my linq etiquette.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on actually how you implement the filter logic. If you want to find list of type A having a type B containing at least one active flag then you can do like below.

```
listOfTypeA.Where(a => a.ListOfTypeB.Any(b => b.Active)).ToList();
```